# Installing APScheduler to Python 3.8

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, scheduler, apscheduler

I'm very inexperienced with Python and am trying to install APScheduler to schedule some Python scripts each morning at work.

I used to have it installed and had a working script, but the package disappeared when I had my hard drive upgraded recently. I can't for the life of me remember how I installed it the first time and can't seem to get it to work now. I've tried a bit with pip and easy_install but no dice!

I am using Spyder and Python 3.8 (from the Anaconda package); any help greatly appreciated!

Many thanks,
Harry

Comment: What did you type for pip/easy_install? What did they return?

Comment: @Shoot Tried: 
"pip install apscheduler" and got a long error message saying: "could not fetch URL...." - too long to type here, but kept saying it was skipping things and then couldnt find the ditribution for APScheduler

And "easy_install apscheduler" gave back invalid syntax.

Thanks!